# Xcode10 beta6: Argument labels '(frame:)' do not match any available overloads with UIButton

Tags: xcode10beta6

Xcode10, beta6, in my project code:

let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10,y: 10, width:30, height:30))

then Xcode show me the error: 
Argument labels '(frame:)' do not match any available overloads
1. Overloads for 'UIButton' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (type: UIButtonType), (contentsOfFile: String?), (coder: NSCoder)

Anyone can help?  Thanks very much.